# How can I scale an image up and centre it at the bottom of its container?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scale, centering

I'm trying to make a very simple layout with the following properties:

- Just contains a single image that should be:

  - Scaled up as much as possible while maintaining its original aspect ratio
  - Horizontally centred
  - At the bottom of its container

Here's an example of what it should look like:

[image: portrait view showing image centred at the bottom but scaled up][image: landscape view showing image centred at the bottom but scaled up]

I can get it to scale up and centre horizontally and vertically by setting the image to `match_parent` width and height and specifying [`scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) of [`fitCentre`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html#enumconstants). I could also get it to align to the bottom-right by using [`fitEnd`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html#enumconstants).

I tried using `RelativeLayout` to centre it at the bottom, but I could only get this to work if I set the image's width and height to `wrapContent`, which caused it to not scale up.

Here's a sample layout to use as a starting point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_search" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I simplified your code by moving the `FrameLayout` attributes onto the `ImageView` and removing the `FrameLayout`, and it still worked. Feel free to update your answer with this simplification. Otherwise I can post it as a separate answer. Is there a reason you included two layouts?

Comment: You are right. `FrameLayout` is not necessary, so I removed it. Thanks for notice!